# Restore files deleted from remote Git repo

Tags: git

My colleague accidentally deleted most of the files from our remote repository while playing around with git. I have the latest commit on my local system, but when I try to push those files on to remote git repo, it throws an error saying that remote repo is ahead of the local one. Please pull to update the local repo before pushing.

I made a copy of the entire folder locally (let's call it backup), just to be safe and then pulled from the remote. Of course, that deleted most of the files from my local repo as well. Next, I did `git reset --hard` to the last known commit and then tried to push this to the remote. I still get this error:

`Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)'

I do not know how to fix this now? I can manually copy the files from my backup and then perhaps commit locally and then push. But is this the best way? Please help..

Comment: Have you tried a force push? `git push --force` after your `git reset --hard xyz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest course of action here would be to just `revert` the commit (or commits) that removed the files:

```
git revert <commit reference>
```

This will create a new commit that undoes everything the old commit did, which you should have no trouble pushing to the remote repo.